# Laravel - foreach local variable is overwriting the global variable

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Today i have faced a very strange issue.
I have a controller from where i am sending three variables to the view `sections` `thread` and `threads`.
In my view  i am looping through all the sections with foreach loop like this:

```
@foreach($sections as $i => $section)
```

and for each section i am creating a div and giving that id like this:

`id="{{ $thread->slug }}-{{ $section->slug }}`

now in this div i am looping through all the threads like this:

```
@foreach($threads as $thread)
```

and creating div for each thread.
Now the problem is that when the loop for threads completes the last item in the threads which is store in local variable thread, overwrites the thread variable sent from the view.
Now, i know that to resolve this i can rename the local variable in foreach loop to something else but my question is why is this happening? why is this local variable overwriting my global variable ?

Here is my controller:

```
    public function show($slug)
    {
        return view('thread.show')
            ->with('sections', Section::all())
            ->with('threads', Thread::all())
            ->with('thread', Thread::where('slug', $slug)->first());
    }
```

View:

```
@foreach($sections as $i => $section)
 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="{{ $thread->slug }}-{{ $section->slug }}">
  @foreach($threads as $thread)
   <div class="card mb-3">
    {{--/// Some Html--}}
   </div
  @endforeach
 </div>
@endforeach
```

Now here is the screenshot of the rendered html:

[image: Rendered Html]

The thread name is page-172
the id for the first div is rendered fine but look at he id of other two divs 
`section-341` which is the last item in the `threads`

Comment: `foreach($threads as $thread)` __overwrites__ your original `$thread`.

Comment: yeah i know this as i have mentioned in the question, but i want to know why ?

Comment: Because there're no global and local variables here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but my question is why is this happening? why is this local variable overwriting my global variable

Because php cannot differentiate between `$thread` and `$thread`.

While you could expect the variable `$thread` in the context of `foreach($threads as $thread)` to live only within the `foreach` body, in php this is not the case.

The local variable `$thread` exists within the scope of your view, not your loop body.
Since php does not differentiate, the original is overwritten.

Comment: oh... so the local variable created in the body of loop can be accessed from the outside in php ??

Comment: Exactly; the scope is not restricted to the loops themselves. You cannot use a local variable outside of the view, or outside of the function/method it was created in. For more information, see [the manual on scopes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)